# Angular, Angularfire2, Getting the average of numbers in the database

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I been trying to figure this one out for days. I feel like its alot more simple than I think. I am using angular and angularfire2 i have a rating system set up and essentially what I am trying to do is query the collection and get the number field in each document, add them together and get the average. All I know how to do however is query the database, and display all my review in the template and how to get the total number of documents in the collection so i have the number to divide by. I can't figure out in my typscript file how to get all those values and add them together to then get and average.

```
this.reviews = db.collection('dispensaries').doc(this.id).collection('reviews').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
    console.log(data.stars);
    return data;
  });
});


db.collection('dispensaries').doc(this.id).collection('reviews')
  .ref
  .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.size);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar problem, but I was able to obtain the data and put the number in a variable, the problem is that I can not perform the update in firestore internally but I attach a code that may work for you, this method takes 2 parameters: id and a number (amount) that must be added to the existing one, the existing one I get it with the method get.

Code:

```
this.afs.doc(`productos/${id}`).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    const reemplazarCantidad = doc.get('cantidadActual') + cant;
    console.log('Datos:', doc.data());
    console.log('Hay:', doc.get('cantidadActual'));
    console.log('Se debe sumar: ', cant);
    console.log('total: ', reemplazarCantidad);
  } else {
      console.log('No hay datos');
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
});
```

}
and as is logical in the constructor I declare afs as angularfirestore

```
constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
```

Well the solution that I found now is:

in the service.

```
 agregaCantidad(id, cant){
this.afs.doc(`productos/${id}`).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    const reemplazarCantidad = doc.get('cantidadActual') + cant;
    doc.ref.update({cantidadActual: reemplazarCantidad});
  } else {
      console.log('No hay datos');
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
});
```

}

and call the method:

this.xxservicexx.agregaCantidad(idProducto, cantidad)

note: a part of this solution involves recording as product id the name of the product itself. This seemed to me the most practical.

but I'm not sure if it's the right one or the best,

Thanks, and best regards.
ML